# How to use static typing with scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, mypy

I am trying to implement static typing with Scrapy, I couldn't find any specific ways to do it. Any help in this regard would be great.

Comment: Scrapy doesn't have type hints yet (see [issue #4041](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/4041)). You can write your own [stub files](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html) for Scrapy though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will look into creating the stub, although this might be an overkill.

Comment: You don't have to type everything, only what you are actually importing in your project.